# Prove that the tensor product of unitary matrices is also unitary

Tags: tensor-products, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are unitary matrices, then $C = A \otimes B$ is unitary.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(A\otimes B)^{\dagger} = A^\dagger \otimes B^\dagger$, where $A^\dagger$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A$.

Comment: So $AA^\dagger = I = BB^\dagger$ by definition of unitary. Thus, $CC^\dagger = (A \otimes B)(A^\dagger \otimes B^\dagger) = (AA^\dagger \otimes BB^\dagger) = I \otimes I = I$ therefore, $C$ is unitary?

Comment: technically you need to take care of the $A^\dagger A$ direction too but yes that's right :)